# If $ \ m=\inf \{f(x,y): \ x \in D \} \ $ and $ \ D=[a,b] \times [c,d] \ $

Tags: real-analysis

If $ \ m=\inf \{f(x,y): \ x,y \in D \} \ $ and $ \ D=[a,b] \times [c,d] \ $ . Then prove that,

$ \inf \{f(x,y): \ x \in [a,b] \}  \geq m \ $ for every $ \ y \in [c,d] \ $

**Answer:**

We know,

$ \inf \{f(x,y): \ x,y \in D \} \leq \inf \{f(x,y): \ x \in [a,b] , \ y \ \ is \ \ free \} \ $

$ \\ \Rightarrow m \leq \inf \{f(x,y): x \in [a,b] , \ y \in [c,d] \} $

**Am I right so far ?**

**Help me out**

Comment: Either $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R$ or on $\mathbb R^2$. But you mixed it. Therefore your hypothesis doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I made correction in the question . It was my fault.

Comment: ... or simply $A\subseteq B\implies \inf A\ge \inf B$

Answer (score 0):

> *$y$ is free*

is a bit fishy, because $y$ isn't "free", but fixed! It is much easier to argue like Hagen von Eitzen wrote:

Define $A_y=\{f(x,y)~:~x\in[a,b]\}$ and $A=\{f(x,y)~:~x\in[a,b],~y\in[c,d]\}=\bigcup_{y\in[c,d]}A_y$.

So $A_y\subseteq A$ for all $y\in[c,d]$. Hence $\inf A_y\geq \inf A$ for all $y\in[c,d]$.